# No Document classes found in LyX on Mac 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: lyx, mac, mactex

I installed MacTex 2014, and then LyX, but when I start LyX up all the document classes are unavailable. Reconfiguring does nothing. Do you have to add something to the path for LyX to know where to look?